# Unable to Present an Interstitial Ad on the launch of a view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to load an interstitial ad on the view controller as soon as it appears. But, I don't see anything on the screen as I launch my app. This is the code I used to achieve it:-

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class MainViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if (interstitial.isReady) {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
  
}
```

Any help will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

It may be failing the `interstitial.isReady()` because it's just not ready yet. Then since there's nothing after your `if() statement`, it just ends without doing anything else.

Have you tried adding an `else()` statement to account for the ad not being ready yet?

Edit:

Wait, don't you need to createAd()?
Similar code examples I've seen have: interstitial = createAd()

Comment: It is working only when I deploy the if else statement to a button. Thus, it is showing an ad after the button is clicked

Comment: Do you need to call createAd()?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Let me give it a try:)